# How to remove empty div created by routing.yml file by specified routes?

Tags: 8, routes

I have 2 routes

```
games.one:
  path: '/math/one'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\games\Controller\GamesController::one'
    _title: 'My Title'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'


games.two:
  path: '/math/two'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\games\Controller\GamesController::two'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Route `games.one` has `_title` and Route `games.two` does not have. Now the issue is When I access route game.two, It shows an empty div for title.

**How to remove this empty div?**

Comment: Better, you need show code class controller. What's code in controller **GamesController::one**

Comment: edit the page.html.twig

Comment: go to the block layout and change the visibility of the *Page Title* block to not show on `/math/two`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the page.html.twig for that page and stripping out the title.

To override the template for that specific page you should probably alter the hook suggestions:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'games.two') {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__no_title';
  }
}
```

Now you can copy the page.html.twig template to  your theme folder, rename it to page--no-title.html.twig and strip out the title tag.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think have a lot of way do that. But if you want use preprocess better choose _preprocess_page_title() and set variable title to false.